# A start job is running for dev-disk-by

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

Machine:

- Latest Kubuntu on laptop.

What I've done:

- Do-dist-upgrade
- After the upgrade was complete I powered off the laptop by the power button

Problem:

- A start job is running for dev-disk-by, then "you are in emergency mode" login appear.

What I've tried:

1. Edit `fstab` to make sure nothing is wrong; the UUID is exactly same with a partition.
2. Changed UUID to `/dev/sd*`, but the problem persists.
3. Reinstalled the kernel, but the problem still persists.
4. `dmesg | grep` failed, `return "_OSC Failed (AE_NOT_FOUND); disabling APSM`.
5. If I run from recovery mode and select `dpkg` or `fsck`, then resume booting, it worked and I came back to the desktop. However it worked only if I select `dpkg repair` or `fsck`. I thought those operations `mount /` in `rw`. If I resume booting from recovery mode without selecting those operations, the main problem persists. Emergency mode.

**Update 1:**

I think it was because partitions in `fstab` were not mounted at normal boot although the UUID is exactly the same.

I went to recovery mode and entered the root shell to`mount -a`, and checked if all partitions are mounted. They are. There is nothing wrong with the `fstab` content, but it won't mount at boot.

When the /boot and /home entry are commented out in `fstab`, the machine boots well (with the user profile reverting to default, of course).

**Current solution:**

Enter emergency mode, do `mount -a`, logout as root (which implies exit), do `startx`, login as normal user. It works like a charm, but `fstab` isn't automatically mounted.

**Edit:**

Problem solved by changing `linux-image*` and `linux-header*` to `4.4.0*` and do `sudo cat /etc/mtab | grep sda > /etc/fstab` (yes, > used instead >>), but swap is not automatically mounted and activated, but it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I had a failing cable to an external HDD. I ran it down by doing mount -a after the "emergency" screen came up and noting which UUID= were failing. If you run into this and have externals attached, it's worth checking out that aspect of it.